# iOS Delegate to prevent invalid inputs

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I'm learning iOS development and am trying to prevent a UITextField to have values which have multiple decimal values such as "45.3.1" and alphabetical characters.

The preventing of alphabetical characters functionality is not working as I intended. If I print `alphabeticString` when entering a number in the text field I get `nil` though when I print `alphabeticString` when entering a character such as 'a' I get an optional range. For some reason my if statement always returns true when there is a character inserted even when `alphabeticString` prints as nil.

Any reasons why? Thanks.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField,
        shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
        replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let existingTextHasDecimalSeperator = textField.text?.rangeOfString(".")
    let replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator = string.rangeOfString(".")
    let alphabeticString = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet())

    if existingTextHasDecimalSeperator != nil && replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil && alphabeticString != nil {
        return false
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Stepping through this code with the debugger will show you which line has a logic error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I'm not sure why that isn't working.  Why don't you use a 'Decimal Pad' keyboard type for your `textfield`?

If for some reason you don't want to, try this:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    switch string {
    case "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9":
        return true
    case ".":
        if let _ = textField.text?.rangeOfString("."){
            return false
        }else{
            return true
        }
    default:
        if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet()){
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

EDIT: I think I found the problem in your code, you need to separate the `if` statement into two conditions:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let existingTextHasDecimalSeperator = textField.text?.rangeOfString(".")
    let replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator = string.rangeOfString(".")
    let alphabeticString = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet())

    if (existingTextHasDecimalSeperator != nil && replacementTextHasDecimalSeparator != nil) ||  alphabeticString != nil {
        return false
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using a decimal pad keyboard type, however if someone is using a bluetooth keyboard, they can get around this by mistake. Thanks for your answer, very helpful, though I'd curious to know why my code doesn't work.

Comment: @PSidhu I edited my answer, I think I found what was wrong with your code :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use predicates. They make life much easer!
In your case, code would be next:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard (textField.text != nil) && (string != "") else { return true }
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "[0-9]{1,}+\\.{0,1}[0-9]{0,}")
        let resultString = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
        return predicate.evaluateWithObject(resultString)
}
```

Just 4 lines.

Best regards!